# WP7: live video streaming

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, live-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

I have smooth live streaming SMF player in wp7 application .
At the first launch it works fine.

I mean video streaming is working. But when I run it a second time, it does not work but is not producing any errors.
My XMAL code is:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="WP7 Smooth Streaming Demo" Height="12" Width="266" FontSize="22" Foreground="Blue"/>
                <Core:SMFPlayer Name="strmPlayer"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Margin="0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

And my C# Code is

```
PlaylistItem item = new PlaylistItem();
 item.MediaSource = new Uri("http://video3.smoothhd.com.edgesuite.net/ondemand/Big%20Buck%20Bunny%20Adaptive.ism/Manifest");
            item.DeliveryMethod = Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming;
            strmPlayer.Playlist.Add(item);
            strmPlayer.Play();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem of multi resolution video.Because wp7 not support all resolution video.

So when you run your application on device at that time use RestrictTracks Method.
[RestrictTracks Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.streaminfo.restricttracks%28VS.90%29.aspx)

I think its bit rate problem of your video.

Please reffer this tutorial[Developer Guide For nokia lumia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Video_playback_guidance_for_Nokia_Lumia_610)

If any problem than let me know

Comment: @yes its bit rate issue because my video bitrate is 420992 and this methos allow 400000 bit rate

Comment: when i run first time that time it will play than after its not working

Comment: Okay so use RestrictTracksMethod that already i given you.this method allow 1000000 bit rate.Hop its working